# Have sudo ask the password of the user that it's switching to

Tags: sudo

```
sudo -u user1 command ...
```

How can I make `sudo` ask the password of `user1` instead of the password of the current user?

---

**Background**: I want to use this in a Git Hook that is executed by the user `git`, something like

```
echo "PasswordOfWww" | sudo -Su www bash -c "cd site; git pull; ./deploy.sh"
```

I've tried using `su www -c "command ..."` but it tells me

```
remote: su: must be run from a terminal
```

when I push to the repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7747/is-it-possible-to-su-without-being-prompted-for-a-password "Is it possible to su without being prompted for a password?", where a solution using `expect` is offered.

Comment: If you want the password of the user being switched _to_ rather than the one being switched _from_, use `su`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to store any user's password unencrypted in the filesystem if you can avoid it.  It depends a little how much you're relying on the portability of the code you have in git vs. what you can store on the local filesystem.  I'd recommend using sudo with NOPASSWD with as restricted of a command as you can.  You'd make a /etc/sudoers entry something like:

```
git ALL=(www) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/deploySite
```

Where `deploySite` has various checks in it to make sure the user is going into the correct directory and the `deploy.sh` script doesn't have anything sketchy in it.

If you trust user git to use user www's account responsibly, you can use NOPASSWD:ALL.  But you're basically allowing whomever has access to upload to git access to run any command they want as user www.

#### But to answer the original question

You can have sudo ask for the target user's password rather than the calling user.  You'd put a sudoers entry like:

```
Defaults:git targetpw
```

Then user git will have to type the password of user www when he runs `sudo -u www ...`.

Comment: My Git server is not currently used by multiple users, but if it were, I would not want anyone else but myself be able to execute the command from the repository and Git Hook that I specify. Thus, the only way I can think of is putting the password plain text into the Git hook. I see that both, your answer and my approach with going for a password in plain text, have their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Ok, technically, the Git hook could start an arbitrary program and upload all other, even private repositories, to another server, so, I guess it's not a very protective environment anyway.

Comment: One of the things I'm saying is I think it's always better to use NOPASSWD than to store the password.  If you use NOPASSWD, then the sudo -u www command won't ask for a password if it's an allowed command.  If you try to pass the password to sudo (which you generally can't), then you have the password file lying around your filesystem, any backups, the process table when the command runs, and anyone who got it could use it to log into the machine remotely.  To set NOPASSWD just means anyone already logged in as git could run one or a list of commands as www.